# App works fine in iPad, iPhone, but sometimes crash after make a build

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

An app works fine in both ipad and iphone but after made build for same app and use that build, it crashes on iPad (works fine on iPhone).

My code:

```
-(void)everyBodyButtonClicked {
    if([InternetUtility testInternetConnection])
    {
        UIButton * everyBody = ((UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:_wallEverybodyButton_tag]);
        UIButton * bestMatch = ((UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:_wallBestMatchButton_tag]);
        UIButton * favorite = ((UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:_wallFavoraiteButton_tag]);
        everyBody.selected = YES;
        bestMatch.selected = NO;
        favorite.selected = NO;

        // add code
        everyBody.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        bestMatch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        favorite.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        // add code end

        collectionData = nil;
        collectionData = [[DataController sharedInstance] getEveryBodyData];
        [self reloadData];

        if(collectionData == nil)
        {
            printf("\n\nif(everyBodyButtonClicked / collectionData == nil)");
            DDLogVerbose(@"getEveryBodyDatafromStart Data not found in cache");
            [self getEveryBodyDatafromStart];
        }
        [AppDelegate sharedInstance].isButtonTab = EVERYBODY_TAB;

    }
    else
    {
        [ViewUtilities showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"", nil) :NSLocalizedString(@"Check network connection", nil)];
    }
}
```

Comment: This very less information to judge what is exact problem. Please provide some detail information so one can answer correctly.

Comment: Before creating build, you should test your application in development environment by connecting your device.

Comment: I already tested, it is woking @ iphone

Answer (score 0):

Your should give some useful information to resolve your question. But you can connect devices and debug to get that error. I think it's because you sent some messages which is not supported with device's OS